# Prediction using .pb model which was exported using keras api

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, prediction

I created and saved a model using keras api(using tensorflow 2.0):

```
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *

training_data_df = pd.read_csv("03\sales_data_training_scaled.csv")

X = training_data_df.drop('total_earnings', axis=1).values
Y = training_data_df[['total_earnings']].values

# Define the model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=9, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(50, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

# Train the model
model.fit(
    X,
    Y,
    epochs=50,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=2
)

# Load the separate test data set
test_data_df = pd.read_csv("03\sales_data_test_scaled.csv")

X_test = test_data_df.drop('total_earnings', axis=1).values
Y_test = test_data_df[['total_earnings']].values

test_error_rate = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, verbose=0)
print("The mean squared error (MSE) for the test data set is: {}".format(test_error_rate))

# Save the model to disk
model.save("04/model/trained_model")
print("Model saved to disk.")
```

which saves the model in .pb format. I know that i can load the model using :

```
import tensorflow as tf

graph = tf.Graph() 
graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
graph_def.ParseFromString(pb_file.read()) 
with graph.as_default():
  tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
```

**But I am confused about how to predict after loading the model?** I stumbled upon [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/custom-vision-service/export-model-python) which talks about  names of input and output parts of the model before prediction. **My question is, How to find those names and then predict the model when i created the model using Keras api**?

Here is the code for prediction from the link:

```
# These names are part of the model and cannot be changed.
output_layer = 'loss:0'
input_node = 'Placeholder:0'

with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
    try:
        prob_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name(output_layer)
        predictions = sess.run(prob_tensor, {input_node: [augmented_image] })
    except KeyError:
        print ("Couldn't find classification output layer: " + output_layer + ".")
        print ("Verify this a model exported from an Object Detection project.")
        exit(-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code for predicting by using .pb file:

```
    import tensorflow as tf
    with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
        tf.compat.v1.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.compat.v1.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], './folder_in_which_your_pb_model_is_saved')
        graph = tf.compat.v1.get_default_graph()
        y_pred = sess.run('your_output_name:0', feed_dict={'your_input_name:0': x})
```

Here is how to find out the names of the layers. Type the following code in the terminal - activate your environment if you're not using root:

```
saved_model_cli show --dir {folder_in_which_your_pb_model_is_saved} --all
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Save the model 
model.save('saved_model/my_model')
#Load the model 
import tensorflow as tf
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')

# Check its architecture
new_model.summary()
#Predict model
new_model.predict(input)
```